# WTForms "too many values to unpack" with SelectField

Tags: python, forms, wtforms

I'm using WTForms and I'm trying to display a `SelectField`, but I get the following error:

```
>>> form.status()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\wtforms\fields.py", line 136, in __call__
    return self.widget(self, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\wtforms\widgets.py", line 237, in __call__
    for val, label, selected in field.iter_choices():
  File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\wtforms\fields.py", line 390, in iter_choices
    for value, label in self.choices:
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Here's my form:

```
class TestForm(Form):
    status = SelectField(u'Status', choices=Test.statuses())
```

The `Test.statuses` static method returns a list of strings.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[It expects a list of `(str, str)` tuples, not a list of strings.](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6/fields.html#wtforms.fields.SelectField)

Answer (score 6):

Never mind, it needs tuples, not strings:

```
>>> form.status.choices = [(status, status) for status in Test.statuses()]
>>> form.status()
u'<select id="status" name="status"><option value="Status1">Status1</option></select>'
```